# How do I make a loading structure when I try to fetch an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loading

I try to make a loading on my login function, when I call the login **API**, the word of **loading** (will make a CSS design later) will shown out first, when the API is successfully called, it will go to another page.

Consider the code below:

```
login(){
  const { history } = this.props;
    PostData('api/users/login', this.state)
    .then ((result) => {
      let responseJSON = result;
      this.setState({loaded: true})
        localStorage.setItem('loginEmail', this.state.loginEmail);
        localStorage.setItem('id', responseJSON.user.id);
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', responseJSON);
        {
          this.state.loaded ? (
            
             history.push('/Home')
          ) : (
            return(
              <>
                <div>Loading</div>      //I get the error here
              </>
            )
          )
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

```
constructor (props){
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    loginEmail: '',
    loginPassword: '',
    error: {},
    loaded: false,
    redirect: false,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
  this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

So I believe the way I use was conducting any mistake. Any other more suitable and easy way to make a **loading** structure for fetching api?

**Update**:

Here is the error :

[image]

> Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: What error did you get actually?? Can you elaborate your issue in detail??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan the error was "Fail to compile" "Parsing error: Unexpected token"

Comment: Can you try using like this, ```{
            return(
              <>
                <div>Loading</div>      //I get the error here
              </>
            )
          }``` .. Remove ```(``` and include ```{``` before return, same way for closing tags also..

Comment: Also I believe there is no need of return you can directly give ```<div>Loading</div>``` inside ```:``` (else) statement.. Like ```this.state.loaded ? (

             history.push('/Home')
          ) : <div>Loading</div>```

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Not working, I try to remove ```return``` and it come with the error of **Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.**

Comment: Same, also get the error of ```Parsing error: Unexpected token``` on return

Comment: Okay in removing the return statement I suspect , you might be missed something.. You can take a look at the link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-display-conditional-content-with-ternary-or-if-statement-yybzk It works fine.. So your total code should be like ```{
          this.state.loaded ? (

             history.push('/Home')
          ) : 
                <div>Loading</div>  

        }``` Please consider the opening and closing brackets..

Comment: @kokoka Did any post solved your problem? Kindly inform us if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Make a boolean variable eg.

```
this.state.loading = false;
login(){
 this.setState({
  loading:true;
 })
 api.login().then(response=>{
  this.setState({
   loading:false;
  })      
 })
}
render(){
     return (
     this.state.loading?('<div>Loading...</div>'):('your html page')
   )
}
```

You can read about **Conditional Rendering** from here [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)